# В чем ошибка присвоения действия при нажатии на Маркер Google Maps?

Tags: java, google-maps-api

только на третий-четвертый раз срабатывает действие, которое работает при нажатии на определенный маркер в Google Maps. В связи с чем такое происходит? Вроде в коде проблем не видно. Возможен ли какой-то конфликт?
Сам код:

Main.java

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    ...

    Lenin = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(LatLng));
    Lenin.setTag(0);

    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
}

public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

    ExampleBottomSheetDialog bottomSheet = new ExampleBottomSheetDialog();
    bottomSheet.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "exampleBottomSheet");

    if (marker.equals(Lenin)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Кот: ",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return false;
}
```

ExampleBottomSheetDialog.java

```
public class ExampleBottomSheetDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
private BottomSheetListener mListener;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_layout, container, false);

    Button button1 = v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    return v;
}

public interface BottomSheetListener {
    void onButtonClicked(String text);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    try {
        mListener = (BottomSheetListener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                + " must implement BottomSheetListener");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Что говорят логи?

Comment: @Эникейщик
`E/GPSenseEngine: NcFix
E/GPSenseEngine: STC_NC
E/GPSenseEngine: FindHowDetectSatellites 
request:CGX_IOCTL_CANCEL_RECEIVE ret = 0
W/AlarmManager: triggerList.size = 0, mNextWakeup/mNextNonWakeup set to 0
E/GPSenseEngine: AutonomousTermination is enter,return val is -3
E/GPSenseEngine: ====>>>>cgdriver request:CGX_IOCTL_RESET ret = 0
request:CGX_IOCTL_READ_SYS_REG ret = -3
E/GPSenseEngine: AutonomousInitilizeNew and CgHardwareSemiReset
E/GPSenseEngine: ====>>>>cgdriver request:CGX_IOCTL_RESET ret = 0
request:CGX_IOCTL_PREPARE_RECEIVE ret = 0`